# CakePHP: Call to a member function allow()

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

ProtectedController.php

```
<?php

class ProtectedController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index')
        )
    );

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 2
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }
}
```

AppController

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');


class AppController extends Controller {


}
```

UsersController

```
<?php

App::uses('ProtectedController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends ProtectedController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
    }
}
```

I've been having

```
Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function allow() on a non-object    
File: /Library/WebServer/Documents/cakephp_stats/app/Controller/ProtectedController.php 
Line: 18

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp
```

errors right now.

Does someone how to solve this. From what I am seeing it should load the component in ProtectedController and AuthComponent would be loaded.

EDIT:

line 18 is this of the ProtectedController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}
```

EDIT:

Only fix I can do right now is to cut this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);
```

to AppController then override then allow everyone there:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index')
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }
}
```

Comment: You will required to add $components in UserController

Comment: @MoyedAnsari I don't seem to need it in the UserController.

Comment: does add function __construct() { parent::__construct(); } in your protected controller fix it?

Comment: In ProtectedController.php try to add 

$this->Auth->authenticate = ClassRegistry::init('User');

as first line in beforeFilter(); function

Comment: Extending two controllers for the same thing is not something I would recommend. Everything in ProtectedController can be in either your UsersController or your AppController. Keep things as simple as possible and you'll find it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a similar thing. The main differences to your controllers are:

- My `AppController` includes the `Auth` component as well, and does a `$this->Auth->allow()` in its `beforeFilter`.
- My `ProtectedController` does not state login/logoutRedirects, and calls its parent's `beforeFilter`.
- My UsersController does not extend the `ProtectedController` at all. My protected controllers just include the `Auth` component and call their parent's `beforeFilter`.

Just speculating: The default Auth component redirects to /users/login if an unauthorized person tries to access a protected resource. As you're protecting the UsersController and *not* allowing the `login` action, maybe this causes the behavior you experience.